# Rounded Corner Should be constant in Powerpoint VBA script

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I was working on below given script to convert all the corners in rounded corners, but the rounded corners are not giving same values for all shapes.

I have worked on below scripts

```
Sub RoundedCorner5()


    Dim oShape As Shape
Dim sngRadius As Single ' Radius size in points

sngRadius = 0.05
For Each oShape In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange

    With oShape
         oShape.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle
         oShape.TextFrame.WordWrap = msoFalse
         oShape.TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered
        .Adjustments(1) = sngRadius
    End With
Next
Set oShape = Nothing

End Sub
```

Suppose if I have one small rectangle and one big rectangle the the rounded corner values come different for both shapes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, round corners are **proportional** to the shape size. Here is Microsoft's page about adjustments, please note that the units are not points: [Adjustments object (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.adjustments)

This code should get you pretty close, change RadiusFactor to get the corner size you prefer:

```
Sub RoundedCorner5()
  Dim oShape As Shape
  Dim RadiusFactor As Single
  RadiusFactor = 50
  For Each oShape In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    With oShape
      .AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle
      .Adjustments(1) = (1 / (oShape.Height + oShape.Width)) * RadiusFactor
      .TextFrame.WordWrap = msoFalse
      .TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code works perfect for this job.
Full credits to: Rembrandt Kuipers
Site where the code is: https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2019/09/uniform-rounded-corners-cool-code/

```
Sub RoundAllPPCorners()
  Dim oSlide As Slide, oShape As Shape, RadiusFactor!

  RadiusFactor! = 5
  For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
  For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
      With oShape
        If .AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle Then
          minDim = oShape.Height
          If oShape.Width < oShape.Height Then
            minDim = oShape.Width
          End If
          .Adjustments(1) = (1 / minDim) * RadiusFactor!
        End If
      End With
    Next oShape
  Next oSlide
End Sub
```

Comment: Rembrandt looks *suspiciously* like John Korchok. Maybe edit your post to correct the attribution?